# Code in Braces is not running

Tags: java

In our code that is linked by a JButton in a previous frame, part of it that is inside of braces does not run.

I can tell because the JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE is not working because the program does not terminate. If the braces are taken away, other errors appear.

How do we make it so that this code will run?

```
public class PeopleCreator extends PeopleMove {
    public static final JFrame PeopleFrame = new JFrame("The Lovely Couple");
    ImageIcon girl = new ImageIcon();// pic of girl
    ImageIcon boy = new ImageIcon();// pic of boy
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
    JButton girlDialogue1 = new JButton("Hey " + name
            + "! Hey can you get something to drink");
    // This code below does not run.
    {
        PeopleMove.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PeopleMove.add(girlDialogue1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        girlDialogue1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z) {
                JButton boyDialogue1 = new JButton("");// girls first text
                {
                    PeopleMove.add(boyDialogue1);
                    boyDialogue1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent y) {
                            JButton girlDialogue2 = new JButton("");// boys
                            // first
                            // text
                            PeopleMove.add(girlDialogue2);
                            girlDialogue2
                            .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                public void actionPerformed(
                                        ActionEvent x) {
                                    JButton boyDialogue2 = new JButton(
                                            "");
                                    PeopleMove.add(boyDialogue2);
                                    boyDialogue2
                                    .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                        public void actionPerformed(
                                                ActionEvent v) {
                                            PeopleMove.pack();
                                            PeopleMove
                                            .setVisible(true);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth are you doing with four nested anonymous classes? Surely there's a better way to organize this. And dumping all that code into an instance initializer... even if it worked, it would still be terrible. Basically this whole class should be a method (or two...)

Comment: The synthax is very strange. You declare a static variable, some variable with default visibility and then you write an initialization-block instead of an constructor (which seems not intended, because in the variable declaration, you open an OptionPane). If you remove the outer bracket, you have just code inside the class - but the code must be inside some method (like the initializing block you have), that is the reason it has synthax errors when you remove the brackets. To get to know where the error might be, you should add the main-method which is calling the class.

Comment: Please read the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on some guidance as to how make your question better. As it stands it is horrible.

Comment: @Everyone - I believe that whatever you tell this guy he still wont understand as i think he lacks the basic knowledge of java. So i suggest get a Java beginner book read it and come back to this problem and you will see how you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Code in your braces will be executed every time you create new instance of `PeopleCreator` with the `new` keyword (it is appended to every constructor of current class). I am guessing that you are not creating `new peopleCreator` anywhere but you are refering to static field holding `JFrame`.